# Report For Every Day But Skipping 2 hours

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to generate employee report for every day

Employee Report For Yesterday (12:00 to 12:00)

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE DATE(created) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Employee Report For 24 Hours from Current Time When Job is running

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE (created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

In both the reports i want to skip records from 10:00 am. to 11:00 a.m and 4:00 p.m to 5:00 p.m records on that day

Please help me on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Add one more WHERE condition which tests that timepart of the column value is not in these periods.

Comment: @Akina Can you please help me with the query, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can look like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM emp 
WHERE DATE(created) = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND TIME(created) NOT BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00'
  AND TIME(created) NOT BETWEEN '16:00' AND '17:00';
```